# Solr doesn't want to index data with cyrillic in sql query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an instance of Solr (version 4.8.0) on my ubuntu machine. I'm indexing my data from my mysql database.

I am stuck with ukrainian/russian words in where clause.

I have data-config.xml

```
            <entity name="producer" query="
                    SELECT meta_value as producer
                    FROM all_products_meta m
                            INNER JOIN products p
                                    ON p.unique_supplier_id = m.unique_supplier_id
                                       AND p.supplier = m.supplier
                                       AND p.sku = '${item.sku}'
                    WHERE  m.meta_key = 'producer_name'
                    LIMIT 1">
            </entity>
```

Data is being indexed with the code written above.

```
            <entity name="producer" query="
                    SELECT meta_value as producer
                    FROM all_products_meta m
                            INNER JOIN products p
                                    ON p.unique_supplier_id = m.unique_supplier_id
                                       AND p.supplier = m.supplier
                                       AND p.sku = '${item.sku}'
                    WHERE  m.meta_key = 'Количество элементов'
                    LIMIT 1">
            </entity>
```

Data is **not** being indexed with the code written above.

```
            <entity name="producer" query="
                    SELECT meta_value as producer
                    FROM all_products_meta m
                            INNER JOIN products p
                                    ON p.unique_supplier_id = m.unique_supplier_id
                                       AND p.supplier = m.supplier
                                       AND p.sku = '${item.sku}'
                    WHERE  md5(m.meta_key) = '0dbe474de865913944a00c918e52db2d'
                    LIMIT 1">
            </entity>
```

Data is being indexed with the code written above. 0dbe474de865913944a00c918e52db2d is md5 of 'Количество элементов'.

Does anyone have clues how to use cyrillic in sql query?

Comment: My first suspicion is that the values aren't being processed as UTF-8 at some stage and are being mangled. I found [*this reference*](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#URI_Charset_Config_.28only_needed_before_Solr_4.1.29) discussing how to configure Solr to process arguments as Unicode, but it says this should be unnecessary with Solr 4.1.2 or later. Which begs the question... what version of Solr are you running?

Comment: I use the latest version 4.8.0. I think it is something wrong with  mysql-connector-java

Comment: You could be right, though current Mysql versions support UTF-8 if working correctly. If you haven't already, I would try dropping your Cyrillic query directly into the Mysql client to confirm that it works at that level. Then try making the query through your mysql-connector-java and print your query results to the console to see what you're getting and whether it's the same. Finally, you can double-check your catalina.out (assuming you're running Solr through Tomcat) to double check whether an effort is being made to index the records at all, and if so what error might be causing a rejection